# How can I know the specific row that onclick occured?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an `html` table and in one of the columns I have a `check-box`.
So *each* row has a `checkbox`.
I have a javascript function that is triggered by the `onclick`.
Now what I need is to do something specific with the specific row that the check-box was clicked.
E.g. if I clicked the check box on row 13 I want to be able to do something with the row 13 of the table. The *something* I want to do is replace an html element with another.
I have tried and saw that I can use `document.getElementsByName` or `document.getElementById` but it uses either the `name` or the `id` value.
But for a dynamically generated table I am not sure how to do this. I mean how to associate `name` or `id` to solve this.
What is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: The easy answer would be - jQuery, just listen for a click event on a checkbox, had an attribute for each one with a different name/id, and then in the event handler, extract that info with `$(this).attr('attribute_name_with_id')` - presto.

Comment: @MorganWilde Because, of course, [jQuery is the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif). Have you ever thought about using `this.getAttribute("attribute_name_with_id")`?

Comment: I did, but @Kolink I definitely like the idea of abstraction (given of course you do know the underlying basics of what you're doing). You could still do everything in C, but thank god people abstract their thinking into higher and higher level constructs. There is no need to fear jQuery.

Comment: Unless you actually give a damn about your users being able to load pages in less than half a second ;)

Comment: Well in that case do all the prep work on the back-end? I know bloated js is detrimental to a sites speed, but it's js, not jQuery that's to blame primarily. I know the benchmarks and yes they favor plain js in some instances/case, but as far as I'm concerned - build first with jQuery - then optimise bottlenecks. No doubt that you've heard, that premature optimisation is the root of all evil? :)

Comment: jQuery is nice to use when it's cost-efficient to do so. On SO, I think that the point is to check if jQuery tag is there or not. If it's not, there should be at least a plain js alternative if a jQuery solution is suggested.

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing this is the following

```
<tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" onClick='myOnClickHandler(event, this)' />
  </td>
</tr>
```

-

```
function myOnClickHandler(evt, obj){
  // here obj refers to that specific checkbox which was clicked
  var row = obj.parentNode.parentNode; // this way you can access specific row that is clicked
}
```

Comment: Yes this is better. I was thinking the OP was concerned about the row number specifically. But if it's just to get the dom for the row, this is the answer. :)

Comment: How the hell does this have six upvotes? It relies far too much on the structure. What if the checkbox gets a label added around it?

Answer (score 4):

Ignore all the other people answering blindly...

From my understanding of your question, you have ONE onclick handler on the table itself, and you want to get the row it happened on.

In such a case, you would do this:

```
yourtable.onclick = function(e) {
  e|e=window.event;
  var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
  while(!t.tagName || t.tagName != "TR") t = t.parentNode;
  // t is now the row that the click happened on
}
```

If, on the other hand, you actually have an onclick event on each checkbox, then... well, actually you can use the exact same code. ^_^

Comment: +1, no need to assume that there's a fixed number of parent nodes neither any extra information, in fact, that would lead to serious troubles if that depends on it as soon as the markup has to be changed

Comment: I have one `checkbox` displayed in **each** row of the table. I.e. *each* row has its own checkbox. The function called on the `onclick` would be the same for all checkboxes (in all rows).

Comment: @Jim I'd say don't pretend that the html won't ever change, as it will one day happen and you really don't want to forget that some part of your script depends on that exact html (common mistake: I add a button, and now, something completely unrelated is stopping to work, why ?)

Comment: @Frederik.L:What I was asking is that if this answer covers also my case

Comment: @Kolink:I can not get your example to work.I get:`Uncaught reference error: Invalid left-hand side assignment` in my js console. Could you please give more sample code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it should be `e||e=window.event;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you generated your table, but one thing you could do is use an id for the cell or row I care about and incorporate the row number in the id. For example, set row 13's id to "row_13". Then in javascript (the onclick event to be exact) you can parse the 13 out of the id. Or easier, incorporate the row number into the id of the checkbox itself (the row number that the checkbox is in) and then you don't have to hunt down the checkbox' parent using javascript.

Comment: But when I am in the `onclick` function called when the `checkbox` is enabled, how do I get this `row_id` of the row that the `checkbox` belongs?

Comment: You locate the parent using the appropriate javascript functions. Simpler, though, you could just incorporate the row number into the id of the checkbox itself. The number in the checkbox' id would represent the row that the checkbox is in.

Comment: I was assuming you cared about the actual row number, which is why I went down this path. If not, then UmairP's solution is the way to go.